# How to create attachments in couchDB using RestAPI java client

Tags: azure, nosql, couchdb, bitnami

I have a requirement to store attachment on CouchDB. How will I do it using Java. What APIs I can use? Is there any sample code or documentation I can refer? Currently we are using cloudantdb, but we planing to use CouchDB on Azure

com.cloudant.client.api.Database;
com.cloudant.client.api.model.Response;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use [LightCouch](http://www.lightcouch.org/) Java API

```
InputStream in =  // .. init stream

// save under a new document, a generated UUID is assigned as id.
Response response = dbClient.saveAttachment(in, "photo.png", "image/png");

// save to an existing document
dbClient.saveAttachment(in, "file.pdf", "application/pdf", "doc-id", "doc-rev");

// save under a new document with the given id. 
dbClient.saveAttachment(in, "photo.jpeg", "image/jpeg", "doc-id", null);

// get attachment
InputStream in = dbClient.find("doc-id/photo.jpeg");
// ..
in.close(); // close the stream
```